# Text colors showing on emulator but not phone

Tags: android, colors, android-resources

I have a resource file containing colors which I reference from my layout file to set text color.  The text is set to the assigned colors on my emulator, but the text is all set to black on my phone.

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="myColor1">#eaf0a4</color>
    <color name="myColor2">#1643a4</color>
</resources>
```

**activity_myActivity.xml (layout)**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myActivityID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <View
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/whiteBackground"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world!"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/myColor1"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me!"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/myColor2"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Does anyone understand why text is set to the right colors on my emulator, but the text is all set to black on my phone?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your phone, Go to Settings > Accessibility and switch off the High Contrast Text. It will solve the issue.

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: Any other solution except disabling High-contrast text?

Answer (score 1):

> It may be the reason that the background color is similar to the text color

- change `android:layout_below="@+id/text1"`

Try this . It's not clear in your code .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myActivityID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/whiteBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello world!"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/myColor1"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Click me!"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/myColor2"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]